# HTTP Error 400 returned when accessing MELPA package archive

Tags: package-repositories, let-binding

I'm working on a VM running Centos 7 which ships with emacs 24.3. I wanted to install, use some newer packages requiring > 25.1 so I downloaded the source for emacs 25.2 and built it. When I try to load packages from MELPA it fails. If I run `M-x eww https://melpa.org/packages/` I see the following:

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port.
```

My understanding was that Emacs 25.2 included TLS functionality.  When I evaluate the below it prints `tls IS NOT available`. IS TLS support not included in Emacs 25.2? The Emacs GnuTLS manual states that it is an optional optional add-on. Did I miss something when I built it? Was I supposed to specify that I wanted the TLS library included?

```lisp
(let (tlsAvailable (gnutls-available-p))
  (if (eq tlsAvailable nil) (message "tls IS NOT available") (message "tls IS available")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a start:

Your let-binding is probably not what you want. It just binds two variables to `nil`: `tlsAvailable` and `gnutls-available-p`.

I expect you really wanted this, which binds variable `tlsAvailable` to the result of calling nullary function `gnutls-available-p`.

```lisp
(let ((tlsAvailable (gnutls-available-p)))
  ...)
```

Comment: Ah ok.  Thanks Drew. I am clearly a Lisp newbie.  With the change the result is now "tls IS available". So the question becomes why despite being able to send the request using TLS does emacs 25.2 send a plain HTTP request.

Comment: Please post that as a separate question. Questions should be specific, and not evolve. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems using the emacs 25 package manager (on CentOS 7), which went away when I built the latest. Try building 27.2.

Comment: OK. I may just do that. I haven't been using 25.2 for long but today I noticed another issue which is pretty bad.  Doing a goto End of Buffer leads to 100% CPU and steadily increasing memory consumption until the process is killed.